# Проблемы с выделением памяти при работе с new char

Tags: c++, память, biginteger, new

Пишу класс для работы с большими числами

Само число храню как массив char

```
class BigInt {
private:
    bool is_positive;
    bool is_set;
    size_t size;
    char* number;
```

Мне нужен конструктор считывания числа из строки

Код конструктора:

```
BigInt::BigInt(const string& str)
{
    size_t pos = str.find_first_not_of("-0");
    if (str == "") {
        this->number = nullptr;
        this->is_positive = true;
        this->is_set = false;
        this->size = 0;
    }
    else if (pos == string::npos) {
        this->size = 1;
        this->number = new char[1];
        this->is_set = true;
        this->is_positive = true;
        this->number[0] = '0';
    }
    else if(str.length() > pos)
    {
        if (str[0] == '-')
            this->is_positive = false;
        else
            this->is_positive = true;
        this->size = str.length() - pos;
        cout << " size " << this->size << " " << pos <<" pos"<< endl;
        this->number = new char[this->size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           this->number[i] = str[pos + i];
        }
        this->is_set = true;
    } 
    else {
        this->number = nullptr;
        this->is_positive = true;
        this->is_set = false;
        this->size = 0;
    }
}
```

однако здесь в строчке

```
this->number = new char[this->size]
```

возникает проблема с памятью:
`(Detected memory leaks! Dumping objects ->{272} normal block at 0x011FFC88, 30 bytes long. Data: <1234567890123456> 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 )`

Для того, чтобы не учитывать знак и незначащие нули, учитываю первую позицию не этих символов

Никак не могу понять, что здесь не так :(

P.S.

Ниже конструкторы копирования и операторы присвоения и деструтктор

```
BigInt::BigInt(const BigInt& n)//копирование
    : is_positive(n.is_positive)
    , size(n.size)
    , is_set(n.is_set)
{
    if (n.is_set) {
        this->number = new char[size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this->number[i] = n.number[i];
        }
 
    }
    else
        this->number = nullptr;
}

BigInt::BigInt(BigInt&& other)//перемещения
    : size(move(other.size))
    , number(other.number)
    , is_positive(move(other.is_positive))
    , is_set(move(other.is_set))
{
    other.number = nullptr;
    other.size = 0;
    other.is_positive = true;
    other.is_set = false;
}
BigInt::~BigInt()//деструктор
{
    if (this->is_set) {
        delete [] this->number;
        this->size = 0;
        this->is_positive = true;
        this->number = nullptr;
        this->is_set = false;
    }
}
BigInt& BigInt::operator=(const BigInt& other)//присвоения
{
    if (this == &other) {
        return *this;
    }
    if (this->is_set) {
        delete[] this->number;
        this->size = 0;
        this->is_positive = true;
        this->number = nullptr;
        this->is_set = false;
    }
    if (other.is_set) {
        this->size = other.size;
        this->is_positive = other.is_positive;
        this->number = new char[this->size];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->size; i++) {
            this->number[i] = other.number[i];
        }
        this->is_set = true;
    }
    return *this;
}
BigInt& BigInt::operator=(const int intn1)//присваивание для int 
{
    BigInt other(to_string(intn1));
    *this = other;
    return *this;
}
BigInt& BigInt::operator=(BigInt&& moved)//перемещающий
{
    if (this == &moved) {
        return *this;
    }
    if (this->is_set) {
        delete[] this->number; //удаляем высвобожденную память под обьект
        this->size = 0;
        this->is_positive = true;
        this->number = nullptr;
        this->is_set = false;
    }
    if (moved.is_set) {
        size = move(moved.size);
        number = moved.number; //перемещаем указатель на нужную память
        is_set = move(moved.is_set);
        is_positive = move(moved.is_positive);
        moved.number = nullptr;
        moved.size = 0;
        moved.is_set = false;
        moved.is_positive = true;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: @wololo извините, я немного не поняла вас, разве я не то же самое делаю?

Comment: Забейте, был не прав)

Comment: Ладно, арифметические операторы вы же тоже перегрузили? И там, наверное, тоже работаете с памятью? Всё ли освобождаете, когда нужно?

Comment: @wololo да, перегрузила, но напрямую с памятью там не работаю
там вызваются конструторы в некоторых местах, но как я понимаю в конце должны автоматически вызываться деструкторы.

Comment: Если не вызываются перегруженные операторы, утечка всё ещё есть?

Comment: @wololo да, все равно утечки памяти, при вызове конструктора каждый раз((

Comment: Приведите как можно меньший пример кода, когда проявляется проблема.

Comment: @wololo вызов в main одного конструктора BigInt b("123456789012345678901234567890"); уже ведет к утечке

Comment: Странно, оставил от вашего класса только конструктор и деструктор,. в `main` написал одну строчку `BigInt b("123456789012345678901234567890");`. Код отработал корректно: был вызван один раз конструктор, выделивший память, затем был вызван один раз деструктор, освободивший ранее выделенную память.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы уверены, что правильно используете инструменты для обнаружения утечек?

Воспользуемся Visual Studio и CRT library ([docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019), [habr.com](https://habr.com/ru/post/82514/)), и напишем следующий тестовый код:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#include <crtdbg.h>
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#endif

class test
{
public:
    test()
    {
        std::cout << "test.constructor" << std::endl;
        int size = 10;
        buff = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            buff[i] = 'a' + i;
    }
    ~test()
    {
        std::cout << "test.destructor" << std::endl;
        delete [] buff;
    }
 
private:
    char* buff;
};

int main()
{
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
    _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
    {
        test t;
        //_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    } //Здесь будет вызван деструктор test.
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Приведённый код у меня выводит:

```
test.constructor
test.destructor
```

Но стоит только раскомментировать строку `//_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`, как вывод сразу станет таким:

```
test.constructor
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{125} normal block at 0x00345E68, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <abcdefghij> 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 
Object dump complete.
test.destructor
```

Раскомментированная функция `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` сообщает, что есть неосвобождённая память, и это правда, ведь деструктор класса `test` ещё не был вызван.

Убедитесь, что наличие утечек вы проверяете после того, как будут вызваны все деструкторы вашего класса.

Если вы создаёте экземпляр вашего класса непосредственно в функции `main`:

```
int main(){
    BigInt b("12345");
    ...
}
```

то деструктор будет вызван при завершении работы функции `main`.

Comment: Да, я тоже пришла к выводу, что как раз здесь была проблема, хотя я и следовала инструкции из статьи на хабре...
Спасибо!